# The definition of completion of one measure with respect to a family

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

The following is taken from the book of Revuz and Yor more or less verbatim.

> If $(E,\mathcal E)$ is a measure space carrying probability measure
>   $\mu$, the completion $\mathcal E^\mu$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of
>   subsets $B\subset E$ such that there exist $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal E$
>   with $B_1\subset B \subset B_2$ and $\mu(B_2\setminus B_1)=0$. If
>   $\gamma$ is a family of probability measures of $\mathcal E$, the
>   $\sigma$-algebra  $$\mathcal E^\gamma = \bigcap_{\mu\in\gamma}
>  \mathcal E^\mu$$ is the completion of $\mathcal E$ with respect to
>   $\gamma$.
>
> If $\mathcal F \subset \mathcal E^\gamma$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra,
>   the completion of $\mathcal F$ in $\mathcal E^\gamma$ with respect to
>   $\gamma$ is the family of sets $A$ such that, for every
>   $\mu\in\gamma$, there is a set $B$ such that $A\mathbin \triangle
>  B\in \mathcal E^\gamma$ and $\mu(A \mathbin\triangle B)=0$. We write this $
>  \tilde {\mathcal F^\gamma}$, and it contains $\mathcal F^\gamma$.

It seems that we are missing something in the second part. The sets $A$ and $B$ should in some way be related to $\mathcal F$. What is the correct definition, and is there a reference that I can cross-check this against?

My guess is that we must require $B\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Fixed the title, thanks.